# Why "setWebChromeClient" tries to open web page with Chrome instead of webview?

Tags: android

I did set my webview as below.

```
myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
```

The webview sometimes will be called by this method

```
public void loadThisUrl(String url) {
    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

In other class, it calls `loadThisUrl` Method just like this

```
((MainActivity)mContext).loadThisUrl("http://example-site.com/page1?mode=4");
```

It should render the page in webview, but it sometimes(more than 40%) opens chrome application and renders the destination page.
I don' want that! I always want it stay in my app.

This phenomenon never happens if I use `setWebViewClient` instead of `setWebChromeClient`
But I have to use `setWebChromeClient` for now so I'm in trouble.

How can I prevent it to open chrome application and render the page in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know that you can use both: setWebViewClient and setWebChromeClient? Just set them both and see what happends.

Comment: You taught me a charm!! Thanks